# Water Filter System leaking in multiple places

Tags: plumbing, water, leak, water-filtration

I am trying to install this [water filter](https://goblutech.com/collections/water-filtration-systems-1/products/blu-tech-solo-fixed-mounted-single-stage-0-2-micron-water-filtration-system-with-stainless-steel-pex-fittings) under my sink in my RV. I am using this [Adapt-A-Valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-8-in-OD-Compression-Brass-Tee-Fitting-800609/300096256) to split off into two lines. One to the current faucet and a new one dedicated to a drinking faucet. The joint going to the nickel-colored female part of the adapter that goes onto the existing valve is what seems to slightly be leaking, slow dripping. I've circled in the picture below where this leak seems to be occurring
[image]

On the water filter itself, I've switched out the pex insert with a compression-style, this [one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LTWFITTING-3-8-in-O-D-Comp-x-1-2-in-MIP-Brass-Compression-Adapter-Fitting-5-Pack-HF686805/313501944). The one thing to note on the manual of the water filter is that if you do switch out the insert, to make sure it's NPT threading, for which my understanding is MIP is a type of NTP threading which is what the adapter I bought is. I did about 3 wraps of teflon tape and tightened it as tight as I could. I started with a normal tightness but as it kept leaking I went tighter. Below is an image of where it is leaking from, it appears to be leaking through the teflon tape
[image]

I am not sure what else to try at this point or where could be the problem, any thoughts are much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

For the water filter issue, I reapplied teflon tape and added pipe dope and that solved the leaking.

For the first picture on the Adapt-A-Valve, I bought a new one and the same issue is happening with the joint. There were leaks on the other joints and I tightened them up and then the leak moved to the top joint (nickel female side). I might try a different brand

**FINAL UPDATE**

I bought a third Adapt-A-Valve! Interestingly enough, this one came in a box, instead of a bag like the previous two. This one worked without any issue so I'm thinking there were some defect in the other ones

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: For your update. An o-ring sealed joint should not need to be tightened very much, and in fact, overtightening them can make them leak. So you might be just overdoing that connection if you're trying to treat it as if it were a compression fitting sealing without an o-ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a threaded connection and I see no sign of pipe dope or tape to make the seal on the threaded connection.

For the second one, you can discover the power of tapered brass pipe threads to split plastic female fittings by just winding it tighter, or you can take it out, clean it up, and try taping again, or change to dope.

Male Iron Pipe (MIP) is a flavor of National Pipe Thread, (NTP) yes. FIP is the other one.

Comment: The first one has an o-ring inside of the female nickel part so my understanding is that I didn't need teflon tape on that. As far as the actually part that is leaking, that is how the valve came, it was already one piece so I didn't think I had to do anything extra to it. Are you suggesting I remove the threaded piece and put pipe dope or tape on it? If so, I am curious why they sell it as one piece already together

Comment: If it's leaking in the pre-assembled threaded part, contact the company or return it for a different one. That joint, not the one above it with an oring, is where you say it's leaking. And [edit] those details into the question.

Comment: @User9123  O-rings are fragile.  A nick/pinch/little damage can/will lead to a leak.  The good thing is they are easy to replace and can get a kit containing most sizes.

Comment: Thank you both! I think for that part I am going to try and replace it because I did notice the o-ring gets folded over when the female is extended from the thread, I tried pushing it down with a small object but maybe it's not good enough.

For the second picture, I'm not sure what could be wrong. Is MIP a type of NPT threading? Just to be sure

Comment: A hair or a speck of dirt will also defeat O-rings. As will a scratch on the mating surface if you use the wrong tool to remove them.

Comment: Yes, MIP stands for *male iron pipe*, which is NPT (National Pipe Thread). I would remove and re-wrap that fitting, maybe 4-5 wraps this time, and reinstall.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I was told elsewhere that maybe I wrapped it too much and that's why it's leaking ha so what are your thoughts, should I try more teflon tape or less?

Comment: More. 3 wraps minimum and you tried that. Personally, I think it needs to be tightened more but I hesitate to recommend that  because it is a real possibility to crack plastic fittings... as mentioned in other comment(s).

Comment: Did you tighten that compression fitting with wrenches? You need to.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yes I did, I went as tight as I could possibly go and the leak moved to the top joint (nickel female side/o-ring side). I don't know how I can tighten that part as I can't use a wrench to do it. I might try a different brand. Edit: just realized we were talking about the second picture. I fixed that issue, teflon again + pipe dope. Still having issue with first picture